# How to authenticate ssl client certificates with nginx front-end?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate

I have some URL's that I like protecting with ssl client certificates using directives like these in my apache configs:

```
SSLVerifyClient require
SSLVerifyDepth  10
SSLRequireSSL
SSLOptions +StrictRequire
SSLRequire %{REMOTE_ADDR} =~ m/^127\.0\.0\.1$/ \
  or ( %{SSL_CIPHER} !~ m/^(EXP|NULL)/ \
  and %{SSL_CLIENT_I_DN_CN} eq "xxx" \
  and %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_Email} in {"xx@xx.com", "xx@xx.com",} )
```

There don't seem to be any nginx directives to handle this, so I assume I have to pass everything on to Apache backend.

Which brings me to my question, how to pass encrypted ssl?  All the proxying is decrypting the ssl packets at nginx level before passing them on to Apache.

Comment: You should ask a question about how to do what you want with Nginx. Downgrading back to Apache is not the solution. Using Django (you said mod_wsgi in another comment) can be done in Nginx easily. I do this for MANY sites. Look into uwsgi and Nginx. If you find Apache to be faster, your config is wrong. Ask those questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want Apache to handle the SSL verification, then you'll need to put it in front of nginx, or else do some crazy stuff with passing the client DN to Apache via a custom header or something -- an awful lot of work.

There are *some* facilities for doing DN checking in nginx, though; the [Nginx HTTP SSL module docs](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpSslModule) give the possible variables (right down the bottom, and unfortunately the markup's stuffed so there's no header for it) but `$ssl_client_s_dn` should be what you're looking for, and you can use nginx's programming-like directives (`if $ssl_client_s_dn ~= CN=something_or_other` kind of thing) to redirect or return a 403 if you don't like the certificate presented.  It'll be very different to what you're used to with Apache, but ultimately Apache's way of doing this sort of thing isn't an oil painting either, so it all depends on which ugly you prefer...

I'm curious, though, as to why you'd put nginx in front of Apache... either of them should be capable of doing the whole job of serving web pages.

Comment: Ok, I'll look into the directives bit.  I'm running nginx in front of Apache because I need multiple "all ssl" virtual hosts and SNI seems pretty sketchy.  I still need Apache primarily because of mod_wsgi for Django apps as well as passenger for RoR and php-fpm.  I had a highly tuned Apache before needing multiple SSL sites so wouldn't have changed otherwise.  As it turns out nginx reduced my ssl page loads by around .3 secs or so and is fantastic on the static files so it was a great change.

Comment: Ok, got it working using something pretty close to the direction you pointed.

Comment: The link in your answer is broken, it appears https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#variables is the correct location. Also, you can pass these variables to your interpreter via `fastcgi_param DN $ssl_client_s_dn` if you're using fastcgi, If you're using proxy_pass instead, you can define arbitrary headers, e.g. `proxy_set_header nginx-ssl-client-dn $ssl_client_s_dn` and have the upstream server act on those headers (e.g. PHP behind an Apache upstream server would expose it as  `$_SERVER['NGINX_SSL_CLIENT_DN']`)